# Query syntax not correct

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I'm currently making a cart and i'm having trouble with my SQL query below:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM component WHERE componentID IN (";

            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
                $sql.=$id.",";
            }

            $sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).")";

            $query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

So i'm trying to check the SESSION items with my database items using a select and a foreach. The code loops through the SESSION and adds the componentID to the SELECT, which is then taken into the substr function to remove the last comma (e.g. removing '001,002**,**'. I'm sure the syntax is right, however I keep getting a syntax error which is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '00004,00007)' at line 1

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the full SQL that you try to execute? `echo $sql;`

Comment: Are the values in question truly '00004' instead of 4? Could the left hand zeros be the issue?

Comment: [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/implode) is your friend for concatenating strings with delimiters.

Comment: Yes the values are correct with their 0's as my database uses 5 digit auto_increment numbers. as the componentID's. (an e-commerce site seeling computer components for more detail).

Comment: Your SQL query also becomes bogus if `$_SESSION['cart']` is empty: `"SELECT * FROM component WHERE componentID IN )"` would be the result of that.

Comment: Hmmm, the SQL is appending a comma at the beginning of the values, here is the query Mark: "SELECT * FROM component WHERE componentID IN (,00004,00007)"

Comment: Seems your $_SESSION['cart'] has an empty string as index somewhere. Nevertheless, to avoid this and the empty-problem, just use implode() as in one of the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this line is your problem:

You could also simplify the process of making the comma separated set of id's as ccKep suggests:

```
$sql .= implode(",", $_SESSION['cart']) . ")";
```

The complete code looks like this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM component WHERE componentID IN (";
$sql .= implode(",", $_SESSION['cart']) . ")";

$query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

This will get the *values* from $_SESSION['cart'] - if you really want the indexes of the array, as you first coded it, there's this option:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM component WHERE componentID IN (";
$sql .= implode(",", array_keys($_SESSION['cart'])) . ")";

$query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

array_keys() will extract the indexes of the array and ignore the values.  If you want the values, stick to my first suggestion.

Comment: That's exactly what that line was intended to do... cut of the last comma since it would cause an error. **However, if the cart is empty, the loop doesn't get executed and the whole query becomes bogus.**

Comment: Take another look - I've included code that does not require you to cut off anytihng.  implode() is good for "glueing" arrays together.  If this doesn't fix the problem, please be sure to post a complete query string as created by your code.

Comment: Thanks alot your code worked, i'll definitely read up on implode(). Cheers ccKep and Surreal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM component WHERE componentID IN (";
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
            $some_temp_array[] = $id;
    }
    $sql .= implode(',', $some_temp_array).")";
```

Comment: I have tried this but the syntax is still not correct as it is appending a comma before the first value: "SELECT * FROM component WHERE componentID IN (,00004,00007)"